# Testing functionality of Painless and migration

Tags: eclipse, elasticsearch, migration, kibana

I have two questions 1) How can I test my Painless scripts in eclipse or is there any IDE or any way to test my painless Scripts  2) I need to migrate all my groovy scripts to painless as part of version update, so any insights for getting started would be very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm afraid the tooling support is limited. For example a REPL would be great, but isn't yet available. The tools you'll want to use most are:

   - The [execute API of Painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.3/painless-execute-api.html)
   - [Painless debugging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.3/painless-debugging.html)
2. The migration question is rather broad — I'm not aware of any automated tools for that.

Comment: I see there are examples in both the links you shared, along with the request painless script and the response but my question is where can I do that.

Comment: For instance, If I write a painless script for some functionality 
where can I execute and see the result and validate?
I am wondering if there is a plugin in Eclipse or in any IDE?

Comment: The examples in the docs are to be run in Kibana's Console. You can easily transform them into curl requests, but to my knowledge there is no IDE support or similar.